# testing ip geolocation services

Tags: location, ip

we're using an ip service to tailor out website content to the location the member is browsing from. do you have any suggestions / recommendations for testing tools that would allow us to replicate this scenario of someone browsing our website from a specific ip address? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using [wonderproxy.com](http://www.wonderproxy.com) - it's a commercial service specifically tailored for what you're describing. We've used it ourselves and are quite happy with it.